# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: execution reverted

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, web3js, binance-smart-chain

Here's the code I'm running to get the balance of the contract I've previously deployed to Binance Smart Chain:

```
let Web3 = require('web3');
const fs = require('fs');

let web3 = new Web3('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545');

const contractAddress = '0x43045f0Cec750eEb70478B023885d1956588438E';
const contractAbi = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("scripts/contract_abi.json").toString())
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);

contract.methods.balanceOf(contractAddress).call().then(result=>console.log(result)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This code throws me the error:

```
Error: Returned error: execution reverted
at Object.ErrorResponse (/home/zuber/Projects/HelloBSC/HelloCoin/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
at /home/zuber/Projects/HelloBSC/HelloCoin/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:303:36
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/zuber/Projects/HelloBSC/HelloCoin/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:98:13)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/zuber/Projects/HelloBSC/HelloCoin/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/zuber/Projects/HelloBSC/HelloCoin/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/zuber/Projects/HelloBSC/HelloCoin/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:14)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/zuber/Projects/HelloBSC/HelloCoin/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:61)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:387:35)
at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
data: null}
```

The contract is copypasted from https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc-genesis-contract/blob/master/contracts/bep20_template/BEP20Token.template (only added `onlyOwner` modifier to line 332)

Truffle config used to deploy contract to BSC:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const fs = require('fs');
const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard BSC port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
    testnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545`),
      network_id: 97,
      confirmations: 10,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
    bsc: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org`),
      network_id: 56,
      confirmations: 10,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.5.16", // A version or constraint - Ex. "^0.5.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you change ```let result = getBalance();``` to ```getBalance().then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.log(err))``` and post the output

Comment: Updated code and error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general error originating from a smart contract, when the contract throws an unhandled exception.

Even though that you didn't post the [contract](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x43045f0Cec750eEb70478B023885d1956588438E#code) source code, we can get some basic info about its content from the [decompiled](https://testnet.bscscan.com/bytecode-decompiler?a=0x43045f0Cec750eEb70478B023885d1956588438E) code.

It shows that there's no `balanceOf()` (that you're trying to call), and that the `fallback()` (which is used if you're trying to call an non-existing function) always throws an exception.

---

From here, the most likely possibility is that you meant to deploy a different contract (that contains the `balanceOf()` function) but mistakenly deployed this one instead.

Or if you meant to get the BNB balance (not the token balance) of the contract address, you can use the web3 [getBalance()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#getbalance) method. Example:

```
const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(contractAddress);
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your response!
How did you know that the decompiled code does not contain `balanceOf`? I provided the source code of the contract I deployed and it definitely contains `balanceOf`. Here's it: https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc-genesis-contract/blob/master/contracts/bep20_template/BEP20Token.template

Comment: @Vassily Click the "Decompile Bytecode" on the BscScan under the link. You'll see the decompiled code... Since it's different from the source provided here in the comment, I'm guessing you simply deployed an incorrect contract (possibly a different contract from the same file).

Comment: Do you have an idea why truffle is deploying wrong contract? I ensured that have exacltly same code in /contracts directory but instead of deploying my BEP20 contract it deploy  base contract

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with the same error and the issue was that I was deploying on the remix local address provided by remix but not with metamask. Hope it help someone.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33589575)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).